Libgdx modelinstance rotates about some imaginary circle circumference. NOT its own center y axis!
So confused about how rotation works based on local y axis of modelinstance:
This how I create the modelinstance:
 //create a red box:
            ModelBuilder mBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
            mBuilder.begin();
            Material mat = new Material();
            mat.set(PBRColorAttribute.createBaseColorFactor(Color.RED));
            MeshPartBuilder mpartbuilder = mBuilder.part("boxy", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, VertexAttributes.Usage.Position|VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal,mat);
            BoxShapeBuilder.build(mpartbuilder,10f,0,10f,2f,2f,5f);
            ModelInstance mInstance = new ModelInstance(mBuilder.end());

From code above I can see that modelinstance center is at 10f, 0, 10f.
I create the camera as such: viewing down on the modelinstance:
camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 
Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
camera.position.set(10f,10f,17.5f);
camera.lookAt(10f,0,10f);  //so its looking at the center of 
modelinstance

//so, the up is the Y value of the center point of the modelinstance!
// I did also try:  Vector3.Y 
camera.up.set(new Vector3(10f,0,10f).Y); 
    camera.near = 0.1f;
    camera.far = 300f;

camera.update();

I also try to rotate the modelinstance as such:
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.B)){
        if(true) {
            camera.lookAt(10f,0f,10f);
            Gdx.app.log("rotating", "see");
            Matrix4 mat41 = new Matrix4();
            mat41.set(ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.gameMainPlayerReference.transform);
            //mat41.rotate(new Vector3(10f,0,10f),new Vector3(0,1f,0));
            mat41.rotate(camera.up.Y, 10f * delta);
            //mat41.setToRotation()
            ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.gameMainPlayerReference.transform.set(mat41);
            ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.gameMainPlayerReference.transform.getTranslation(ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.playerCurrentPosition);

            camera.update();
           
        }

        if(false)
        try{
            ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.gameMainPlayerReference.transform.rotate(new Vector3(10f,0,10f).Y,20f);
            camera.lookAt(10f,0,10f);
            camera.update();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Gdx.app.log("the_error","see: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

Both ways of rotating make the modelinstance rotate NOT about its center! It follows the path of an imaginary circle that is centered who knows where!

To add new information to your question, please edit your existing post — do not post a second question about the same issue.
